# DOSBox emulator memory allocation

Tags: ram, emulation, dosbox

Is it possible to assign more memory than default(16mb) to DOSBox emulator, which is running from Ubuntu 16.04 lts?
I'm not using any VM. I've already tried memsize=200 (200 for example), but nothing happens.

Comment: Maximum memory size for dosbox is 63MB.  http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBOX_maximum_memory_size_63_MB

Answer (score 2):

Dosbox is configured in the config file.  The configuration file is located in `/home/$USER/.dosbox/` folder:

[image]

That file should be owned by your user, so double clicking it in your file manager should open your default editor.  Open the file and scroll down to `memsize=` line:

[image]

Change the line to whatever memory total you want in MB, but the maximum size is *63MB*.  Save the file after changing the memory size you want and launch dosbox.

[image]

Hope this helps!